# Display custom message while installation using powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell

i am unable to figure out the mistake that i am doing.The following script will call a bunch of batch files and while the batch files are doing there job, the progress will be shown in a progress bar along with the name of the script. What i want to achieve is to display a custom message during the installation process. I am not able to find out the mistake, any help is deeply appreciated.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") | Out-Null

Set-Location $PSScriptRoot

#Call scripts for installation
$ScriptsHome = Get-Item '.\test\forPS\*'

#Define Form
# Init Form
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.width = 1000
$Form.height = 200
$Form.Text = "** Installation in Progress-PLEASE DO NOT CLOSE THIS WINDOW**"
$Form.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman" ,12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$Form.MinimizeBox = $False
$Form.MaximizeBox = $False
$Form.WindowState = "Normal"
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.Opacity = .8
$Form.BackColor = "Gray"

#Define ICON for Form
$Icon = New-Object System.Drawing.Graphics (".\ICON.jpg")
$Form.Icon = $Icon

# Init ProgressBar
$ProgressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$ProgressBar.Maximum = $ScriptsHome.Count
$ProgressBar.Minimum = 0
$ProgressBar.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,70)
$ProgressBar.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(967,10)
$Form.Controls.Add($ProgressBar)
$Form.Controls.Add($Messages)

#Running Script Name
$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.AutoSize = $true
$Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,50) 
$Form.Controls.Add($Label)

#Define Array messages
#Array
$Messages = @("Preparing to install patch set..Preparing to stop all related processes",
                "Upgrading the application",
                "Copying the missing folder",
                "Applying the patch",
                "Starting all previously stopped Services",
                "Checkcing healthyness of the system after the installation this is may take up to half an hour...",
                "Rebooting Server"
                )
$Messages = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Messages.AutoSize = $true
$Messages.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,50)
$Form.Controls.Add($Messages)


# Add_Shown action    
$ShownFormAction = {
    $Form.Activate()

    foreach ($script in $ScriptsHome) {
        $ProgressBar.Increment(1)
        #$Messages.Text = $Messages[$Messages]
        $Label.Text     = "$($script.Name)"   
        Start-Process $script.FullName -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden
    }
    $Form.Dispose()
}
$Form.Add_Shown($ShownFormAction)

# Show Form
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reusing the same variable name for the list of messages and the label showing the message itself:

```
$Messages = @("Preparing to install patch set..Preparing to stop all related processes",
                "Upgrading the application",
                "Copying the missing folder",
                "Applying the patch",
                "Starting all previously stopped Services",
                "Checkcing healthyness of the system after the installation this is may take up to half an hour...",
                "Rebooting Server"
                )
$Messages = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Messages.AutoSize = $true
$Messages.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,50)
```

Rename one of them (ie. use `$MessageLabel` for the label):

```
$MessageLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$MessageLabel.AutoSize = $true
$MessageLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,50)
```

---

Since you increment the `ProgressBar` by 1 every step, you can reuse the progress bar value to index into the `$Messages` array:

```
foreach ($script in $ScriptsHome) {
    $ProgressBar.Increment(1)
    $MessageLabel.Text = $Messages[$ProgressBar.Value - 1]
    $Label.Text     = "$($script.Name)"   
    Start-Process $script.FullName -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden
}
```